# Can I award my bounty to the user who found the duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, bounty

See this comment:  [Get IntelliJ to show compilation problems automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923304/get-intellij-to-show-compilation-problems-automatically?noredirect=1#comment37230439_23923304)

Throw this on the "broken duplicate incentive" pile.

Per bluefeet, I'm changing this back to support since that's clearly what the discussion, answers and votes are, and opening a separate clean feature request.

Comment: I understand how votes work on meta. Would the downvoter care to explain a more appropriate way to reward the user who solved my problem?

Comment: The correct procedure for a duplicate question with a bounty is to flag the post for moderator attention, asking for the bounty to be removed. Usually the bounty is *refunded* in such cases.

Comment: @MartijnPieters user deserves it though.

Comment: That's still not how it works. Find another deserving answer by that user, and award a bounty to that (post a *new* bounty on the question).

Comment: @MartijnPieters That seems a bit lopsided (awarding a bounty to a user because of a *different* answer by them)...

Comment: I've upvoted your question as I think it's interesting but downvoted your answer, as it seems a very bad practice.

Comment: @Veedrac, awarding a bounty to someone who found a duplicate is also lopsided, as is encouraging duplication within the system by replicating the answer. Just close the question and be done with it.

Comment: Changing this to feature request. Now that I know the official way to do this it's so broken that I should just ask it be possible to do it right.

Comment: -1 after changing this to a feature request. We *really don't want this*.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Agreed. I don't think either "solution" is a good one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not disagreeing, but why don't we want this?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes we do. Can you explain that?

Comment: @Veedrac: With the close hammer we have less need to incentivise dupe finding nowadays, but there are downsides to *hunting* for a dupe that need to be thought through. Right now it takes a moderator to close a bountied question, do we really want to bypass that by hunting for dupes in the hope for the bounty to apply?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the upside is my problem was solved. The bounty worked. The feature request should obviously include solving this properly instead of the most naive way possible.

Comment: @Veedrac: for high-value bounties, we already are getting low-quality posts *just in case* they get the bounty auto-awarded. Bounty hunters finding potential dupes can put another spanner into the works here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If it helps answer the question, solves the reasons for bounties, encourages closing, reduces need for moderator attention *and* increases searchability, then... maybe? I see the downsides. I just don't see it as clear-cut.

Comment: @Veedrac: Regular dupe closing doesn't get us rewards either; I'm quite happy closing OT / dupe bountied questions as is at the moment. They are not a bigger problem than the general duplicated-questions problems. I feel the dupe hammer has addressed most of those, already.

Comment: @Veedrac: Complicating the system further is not needed at this moment. Really, most bountied questions I flag for closing are for questions that are just plain off-topic, this is the first time I've come across a bounty on a question that turns out to be a dupe.

Comment: @djechlin: Great! Your problem was solved, bounty well spent then. :-) That's the goal of the bounty, really, to get attention.

Comment: @MartijnPieters excuse me? a user was screwed out of a reward he was expecting for solving my problem, and was just kind enough to say "well I wanted the bounty, but you seem like a nice guy so I'll help you out anyway while I'm here." and now I have to do an enormous kludge, involve a moderator, find an okay answer of his to make look like a hugely great answer, and you downvote this feature request...  because it's also a problem that answer via duplicate isn't rewarded and we have a close hammer? those unrelated things make this a poor feature request?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can understand the wish to keep the system clean. That is, however, orthogonal to the question of whether the ability to do this is a reasonable request. If the answer is "This is a nice ideal, but it's not practical to implement." I would understand.

Comment: @djechlin: **You don't have to give any bounty**. The user knew what they were doing; they were going to invest some time solving it for you *then did the honourable thing* and pointed to a dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Also note that *you* not needing bounties isn't the same as for a 7k rep user, to whom 250 rep is a *lot* more. :P

Comment: @djechlin: I voted because I don't think we need the feature request; and I've given you my reasons. Your post is a poor feature request for other reasons too; there is nothing in your post explaining why it is needed, for example, or how it would work, considerations about possible abuse, mitigations, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair point re. this not being a full request - I posted a better one in a separate thread seeing as how this is now a mess. re. not awarding the bounty, clearly we have a different notion of fairness and expectation. I would like that user to help me next time I post a bounty, though.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way in place to reward someone for finding a duplicate question that solves your problem.  I wouldn't suggest that person who found it post an answer to your duplicate.

The proper solution would be to request that a moderator refund your bounty and then close your question as the duplicate found.

If you really want to reward the person who solved your problem by finding the duplicate, then you can find a deserving answer of theirs and give them a bounty.

Comment: How is this better than my solution? It involves a moderator, another bounty, and an award on an unrelated but hopefully at least mediocre answer.

Comment: @djechlin The only difference seems to be that content isn't duplicated. That doesn't seem very important if the question's going to be closed, though, and the downside is that this imparts *bias* on an unrelated question.

Comment: @djechlin If you found a duplicate question that solved your problem, why do we need to have an answer posted to your question?  You stated yourself that the other question solved your problem, why do you need an identical answer posted on your question.

Comment: @bluefeet to award a bounty onto it.

Comment: @djechlin, *the commenter doesn't want the stupid bounty!* He took the high road and pointed to the duplicate. Let it go. We do not want replicated content, that's going against the entire purpose of the site.

Comment: @djechlin If you are really grateful to the user, then you can find a deserving answer of theirs and award them a bounty.

Comment: Yes. That's true. I can. That's also a terrible workflow with several problems, which is why I opened a feature request on the topic.

Comment: @djechlin I personally would suggest leaving this question as your `support` question and then opening a `feature-request`.  Problem is that most of the answers here are about your original `support` question and they don't apply to a `feature request`.

Comment: @djechlin: that user has an answer with 148  upvotes. That is a deserving answer, you can award bounty there.

Comment: @Payeli I mean yeah this is what I'm going to do. Still would be better for the user to get a +250 in Java/IntelliJ. He probably would benefit from more publicity there than piling on to his #1. Anyway I opened this up as a separate request. I agree the solutions posted are the best possible, and the problems with them are for a feature request, not dealing with this case.

Comment: +1 I also use this way of rewarding people when I receive help in chat.

Answer (score 1):

If the commented had wanted your bounty that badly, he would have posted an answer regardless of the question being duplicated.

By commenting with the duplicate, he essentially forfeited the bounty. The other solutions of awarding a different answer of his are correct.

Comment: So what we are saying is that we are punishing him for being a good citizen?

Comment: @Veedrac: Not sure how one forfeiting one's own reward constitutes us punishing them.

Comment: it's regarded as bad practice to answer duplicate questions, e.g., by copying and pasting.

Comment: @Veedrac: Lack of reward towards finding duplicates is a known issue, and has been discussed several times. But no one is getting punished. No one is losing anything here.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I would have lost a lot if he didn't post the comment (at no reward) either. Fortunately he got screwed over out of the effort for solving my problem, at which point he was kind of enough to recognize it as a sunk cost and comment the answer.

Comment: @djechlin Which is why I said, if your point is to reward him for helping you, find a different answer he wrote that's worth it, and award it there. The system currently does not allow for awarding bounties on duplicate finds. That's all there is to it. Trying to find ways around it will only result in trouble.

Comment: @SecondRikudo so you're saying he didn't want the bounty bad enough to flaunt good practice, and saying he flaunted the body. *Yes that's the problem this question is about*. This adds no value.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Because bounties are meant to encourage "good behaviour" (high quality answers). As soon as the question is a duplicate, the *bounty encourages bad practice* and *discourages good practice*.

Comment: For starters, write a **better** answer than the found duplicate, and then closing that as a duplicate of the newer question is perfectly acceptable. Second, which is way the correct course of action is to request a bounty refund, and award it elsewhere.

Comment: There isn't a better answer. My problem is fully solved.

Comment: @djechlin **You** aren't the center here. All answers on [so] are expected to help future visitors as well as the OP.

Comment: @SecondRikudo The point is that saying "I'll give you the bounty for writing a better answer" ignores the wish to say thanks for *finding* the answer, especially if that answer is already very good.

Answer (score -10):

My "patch" is to ask the commenter to post a duplicate answer, award the duplicate, then try to get the question closed.

Comment: -1: This causes many more problems than it solves. It also would mean that SO would  need a different policy when bounties are involved. You are definitely not the only person who feels this way, however, the answers that provide ways around this are perfectly valid. Why complicate things?